# iOS Company Name New app just Bundle ID?

Tags: ios, app-store, provisioning

I am submitting a new app to the AppStore in a few days. I've uploaded one app before with a company name. If I upload a new app with com.NewCompanyName.appname will the app be uploaded under NewCompanyName or under the name I uploaded the first app with?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The company name displayed depends on the iTunes Connect account, the underlying Apple Developer account, and any data included in the plist file of the application.

The bundle identifier is just a string used to uniquely identify your application from others for OS-level purposes.  The company naming scheme they recommend is simply an aid to coming up with unique IDs.  You could create bundle IDs like `blert.flargle.vorglast` for all Apple cares

Comment: I've got an individual account, so that means it's just .plist and bundle id?

Comment: It means whatever you set up as your developer name in the account and itunes connect profile

Comment: How can I change it. (hope I can)

Comment: Not much you can do to change it, I investigated this a couple years back, as it was then the only way to change it would be to create a new developer account (costing you another $99)

Comment: But itunesconnect doesn't show me my company name on top of the dashboard, like others said on google/stackoverflow it did. Did they changed their system in a way that you can change the name for every app?

Comment: That I'm not sure of, I don't have access to my company's itunes connect account